# What does this perl script do? Looks tricky

Tags: perl

New to perl scripting. Trying to understand what this does :S

```
@prefixes = ( "ROOT1", "ROOT2" );

$path = <>;
foreach my $prefix (@prefixes) {
    if($path =~ /\/$prefix\/(.*?)(\/|$)/ ) {
        print "$1\n";
        last;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sets an array of predefined prefixes:

```
@prefixes = ( "ROOT1", "ROOT2" );
```

It then reads a path from standard input:

```
$path = <>;
```

For each prefix, it checks if the path starts with a directory name equal to the prefix:

```
if($path =~ /\/$prefix\/(.*?)(\/|$)/ ) {
```

At the same time, it collects whatever follows the prefix (`(.*?)`), up to the next forward slash, or up to the end (`(\/|$)`). If the path matched the prefix, it prints out the collected part and exits the loop:

```
print "$1\n";
last;
```

So, in short, it looks for the first prefix that matches the path, and prints the part of the path following the prefix.

**Edit:** "up to the last forward slash" -> "up to the next forward slash"

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. What would if($path =~ /\/$prefix\/(.*?)(\/|$)/ ) { change to in order to get the 2nd directory from ROOT1 (ROOT1/a/b) where b is returned

Comment: To get the second directory, the regular expression would be: `/\/$prefix\/.*?\/(.*?)(\/|$)/`

Comment: I got ya. I take it that the brackets mean assign to a variable? So /\/$prefix\/(.*?)\/(.*?)(\/|$)/ First directory (a) would be $1 and second (b) would be $2

Answer (score 3):

It prints the next directory in the input of the previous one was ROOT1 or ROOT2. examples:

```
/ROOT1/x/y   -> x
/ROOT1/z     -> z
/ROOT2/bla   -> bla
x/ROOT2/y/z  -> y
ROOT1/x      ->
/bla/x       ->
```